# MDI Parent Form Problem setting Parent

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mdichild, mdiparent

I am using a MDI parent form that has a childs and they show up very well when they are called up by this parent and i use to intensiate child form as

```
ChildForm child = new ChildForm();
child.IsMdiContainer= this;
child.Show();
```

works well as soon as they are called from parent control but if i call them from another form that is not child of any parent form then they no longer remains child of main parent one obvious reason is that when i intensiate them on that independent form is that I simply cannot use child.MDIParent = this; because it will tend to make independent form parent but i also have tried

```
MDIParentForm form = new MDIParentForm 

ChildForm child = new ChildForm();
child.IsMdiContainer= form ;
child.Show();
```

but this also dose not help instead of this it throws an exception that the form that I am trying to set Parent is not MDI Container then to this I give a try and modify

```
MDIParentForm form = new MDIParentForm ;
form.IsMdiContainer= true;
ChildForm child = new ChildForm();
child.MDIParent = form ;
child.Show();
```

and in its result nothing appears

Any idea how to..........

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create a child from another child, just write it like this:

```
ChildForm sibling = new ChildForm();
sibling.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
sibling.Show();
```

Or fire a custom event that the parent can respond to.

Comment: ok this works fine but what if the form from you are going to call the child dose not have any parent lets say from a Parent there is a pop up message that is not child of that form how then what scheme should be adopted

Comment: Lots of ways.  Passing the reference to the parent through the form's constructor is an obvious way.  Even Application.OpenForms[0] would work.  Or giving the parent a static property, there should be only one MDI parent.  Letting the parent take care of creating children is the best way.  That custom event I mentioned.  Or the ShowDialog() return value.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Parent to be the already existing mdiform, not create a new one.

If there isn't an instance of the mdiform already, you should not only create an instance of the form, but also show it.

```
var mdiForm = new MdiForm();
mdiForm.IsMdiContainer = true;
var childForm = new ChildForm();
childForm.MdiParent = mdiForm;
mdiForm.Show();
childForm.Show();
```

Also notice that I use `mdiForm.IsMdiContainer`, AFAIK there is no `IsMdiParent` property.

Comment: Yes I was wrong at the property name.I tried to do your code but did not helped me.instead it showed me a new form dialogue having double control boxes

Comment: My code is showing a new form because the code creates a new instance of the MdiForm. If an instance of the MdiForm already exists, you should set the Parent property to the already existing MdiForm, like I said in the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

write this code in a parent form....

```
childform  obj = new childform( );
               obj.MdiParent = this;
               obj.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
               obj.Show( );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainClass
{
   public string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
   public void showWindow(Form openWin, Form closeWin, Form MDI)
    {
        closeWin.Close();
        openWin.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        openWin.MdiParent = MDI;
        openWin.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Obeng Could you add some explanation to your answer?