# How to render window form after completing any action

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdiparent

I am new in window application and I am not able to render another window form after saving data to database.
 here is my code I am opening the another window form

```
GameList gamelist = new GameList();// the form which I want to open
gamelist.MdiParent = new FrmAdmin();// FrmAdmin is main parent form
gamelist.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
gamelist.Show();
```

But I am getting this error message:

> Form that was specified to be the MdiParent for this form is not an
>   MdiContainer.

any help will be very thankful.

Comment: Why you are not able? Do you get any error message?

Comment: no.. just form is not opening.

Comment: Try to change `new FrmAdmin();` to `this`. Any luck?

Comment: I did this but I am getting this error message "Form that was specified to be the MdiParent for this form is not an MdiContainer."

Comment: Got the solution its worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418604/mdi-parent-form-problem-setting-parent

Comment: OK. Based on the comments I have provided you a working answer below. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're using a MdiParent that is not visible (since you're creating a new one). Try removing this line:

```
gamelist.MdiParent = new FrmAdmin();// FrmAdmin is main parent form
```

and see if the form is displaying correctly.

If you want to show the GameList form inside a MdiParent, you have to use a Form that is already visible.

EDIT:

Looking at your comment, if you're trying to show the GameList form inside the current form, try this:

```
this.IsMdiContainer = true;
GameList gamelist = new GameList();// the form which I want to open
gamelist.MdiParent = this;// FrmAdmin is main parent form
gamelist.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
gamelist.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `IsMdiContainer` of the parent form to `True` and also change `new FrmAdmin();` to `this` and try again:

```
public FrmAdmin()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    IsMdiContainer = true;
}

GameList gamelist = new GameList();
gamelist.MdiParent = this;
gamelist.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
gamelist.Show();
```